# C# how to create a subarray or filtered array based on integers that are above a specific value?

Tags: c#, arrays, integer

I've tried combining multiple other questions/answers but without success.

I have a array containing integers varying from 0 through 10.
Now I need an array with only the integers higher then e.g. 8.

How can I filter or create a subarray which will contain only those integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) for filtering your array:

```
var filteredArray = existingArray.Where(x => x > 8).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ahh I was hoping to get it done with Linq! I was messing around with 'Where' but couldn't get the 'x => x > 8)' part right. Should be okay now. Thanks!

Comment: @Felix Yes, the lambda syntax might be a bit confusing at the beginning, but it's really worth learning more about it.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want LINQ. For example:

```
int[] largeIntegers = allIntegers.Where(x => x > 8).ToArray();
```

Depending on what you need to do though, you may not *really* need the `ToArray` call. For example:

```
IEnumerable<int> largeIntegers = allIntegers.Where(x => x > 8);
foreach (int value in largeIntegers)
{
    ...
}
```

LINQ is capable of *much* more than filtering though - I would *strongly* advise you to learn about it properly - there's a huge amount of material on the net about it. I have a [whole blog series about LINQ to Objects](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx), for example - but LINQ goes beyond just in-process queries too.

You might also want to read Eric Lippert's blog post ["arrays considered somewhat harmful"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx) for reasons to prefer other collections over arrays in many cases.

Another alternative would be to use [`Array.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd.aspx):

```
int[] largeIntegers = Array.FindAll(allIntegers, x => x > 8);
```

... but this then really ties you into arrays. LINQ is more general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LinQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx):

```
(from num in array where num > 8 select num).ToArray();
```

Also you can try:

```
var filteredArray = yourArray.Where(c => c >8);
```

Comment: Indeed, I wouldn't suggest using a query expression for something like this.